# how to create sunken or inlay effect in illustrator to create depth to an object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

Basicly, I need to know what is the best way to add depth to an innerbox like for example a monitor, a tv, anything that comes with a frame.

In my case it's a window frame that contains a poster.

What is the best way to do this, I don't think I need 3d or extrusion.

[image]

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"best way" is a bit ambiguous. There may be one way which works for your style fantastically, but fails for other styles.

Essentially you just need to understand light and shadow. Then it's a matter of creating highlights and shadows accordingly. There are several ways to do that.

- Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow can create a "sunken" look
  [image: inner glow]
- Effect > 3D > Extrude and Bevel with only a bevel applied can create a beveled edge which can give the impression of depth.
   [image: bevel]
- You can combine the two items above to create yet another possibility.
  [image: both]
- You can use gradient fills and strokes. 
  [image: grads]
- You can manually draw highlights and shadows.
  [image: Draw]
- And you can, of course, mix and match among all of these. (Perhaps not the manually drawn and 3D effect  that can create horrible miters)
  [image: mix]

Which method you use really depends upon what appearance you are after.

### Additional after question edit with image

Your sample image is simply using the first option I've presented, Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow. That's all.

Comment: I want to use this frame as a template, maybe the picture can just be done with an innershadow. Is that how it's done here you think?

Comment: Because you'll be using a linked or embedded raster image for the poster, you can't really set up anything easily repeated. With objects you could use Graphic Styles. But a Graphic Style won't apply to a raster images. It's a fairly simple matter (one step) to apply the inner glow though.